# WebComponents-like objects (or nested controls) in Xcode

Tags: xcode, user-interface, cocoa

I created a custom `NSView` that displays some data exactly the way I want it to (a line chart of sorts). I now want to add a couple of sliders to have the ability to zoom the displayed data in and out. I would also like to add a couple of checkboxes so that the incoming data can be interpreted and graphed in different ways, and maybe some scrollbars to be able to see past data. I need to have at least 5 copies of this view (with all its controls) on screen at the same time, each showing a different data feed.

This way of thinking a user interface falls nicely into the WebComponents paradigm where you can design a component that encapsulates many different ones. As I understand it, there is no way of nesting controls like this into a master control in Xcode.

Of course I could layout all the views and all the controls separately inside a view controller and achieve exactly what I want but it would not be as maintainable as having ONE object that I can duplicate either in interface builder or in code.

My question is: what is the proper way to achieve this in Xcode (if any)? I don't need code examples but rather a conceptual answer and I'm only interested in answers related to Cocoa rather than CocoaTouch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just learned that you can have multiple view controllers as [child controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/addChildViewController%3A). This is exactly what I was looking for as it maximizes reusability and reduces maintenance.